# Find the US city from the others

Tags: visual, geography

Based on these cities:

> New Orleans, Atlanta, New Bern, Appleton, Vancouver, and Daytona Beach

Find the city in the US.

Hint 1:

> Louisiana, Georgia, North Carolina, Wisconsin, British Columbia, Florida

Hint 2:

> In a plane (Or close enough to a plane), two points describe a line.

Hint 3:

> Look to where the sun never sets, yet newer than it.

Hint 4:

> Named after a great statesman from my region, I am.

Comment: Does it bother anyone else that Vancouver is on the list?

Comment: He never said the "hint cities" are in the US; just the answer.

Comment: There's also a Vancouver, WA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could the city be:

> Putnam, Connecticut

Because if you map the given 6 cities, then:

> Draw lines connecting certain pairs, they seem to converge in NE Connecticut:
>
>  [image]

And the city of:

> Putnam is right near there

Hint 3 could mean:

> Sun never sets (Britain) but newer = New Britain, Connecticut, which is not far away. It also is New England based on the same reason as the other one.

And Hint 4:

> Putnam is named for Israel Putnam, a Revolutionary War general

And as OP pointed out, there's another possible solution of:

> Webster, Massachusetts, which is just about 10 miles north and is named after Daniel Webster

Comment: You are actually very, very close, so I would accept you due to the nature that your answer is pretty much within the space that I also found.

Comment: If you want to point me in the right direction, I could add your intended answer to this one.

Comment: Pedantry alert: those "straight lines" aren't actually straight except on a map with a particular type of projection.  It would be interesting to concoct a puzzle like this using great circle routes instead.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert It was acutally harder to do this with the "incorrect" straight lines required by the puzzle, because Google Maps has switched to having user-drawn lines match the projection.

Answer (score 3):

Is it:

> Montgomery, AL
>
>  It is the only place the paths would cross, if going in a straight line.

Comment: Nice idea, but not what I am thinking of.

Answer (score 3):

> Galesburg, IL?
>  [image]

Reasoning:

> If you draw lines between the cities (and extend the line from Daytona to Atlanta), they all cross at (roughly) the same point. In my image, they still form a triangle, but as this depends heavily on the projection, they might have crossed at one single point when you designed the puzzle. As Vancouver is way far from everything else, this is probably the line that got distorted most, so let's take the other two. Galesburg seems to be the only city that's close to this intersection.

Edit: If you

> connect Vancouver with Atlanta, New Orleans with New Bern, and Daytona Beach with Appleton, you get a better match. But the intersection is at Sandersville, Georgia, and i wouldn't count "right in the middle of nowhere" as a valid answer, which is why i dismissed it. There's still the antipode, but there's no island there that could belong to the US.

Hint 4 might correspond to

> Washington, which seems to be the county name (?), and is shown by google maps right next to Sandersville.

Comment: Good one, there is actually one point where the lines all meet. You just need the proper city combinations.

Comment: Does "right in the middle of nowhere" count as an answer?

Comment: No, I do have the entire solution, and there is a city (although a small one) as an answer. And the bottom two hints might help if you can understand them.

Comment: See my edit to the question.

Comment: Washington did not come from that region though.